# Como gravar varios registros em uma tabela ao mesmo tempo MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso gravar varios registros de uma só vez no MySQL por exemplo.

Possuo as tabelas `PRODUTOS`, `CATEGORIAS` e uma terceira tabela que relaciona as duas e também um formulário onde eu seleciono a categoria e marco todos os checkbox dos produtos que serão inseridos nessa categoria, preciso que cada checkbox marcado se torne um registro na tabela então assim eu posso ter 'N' registros ao mesmo tempo.

O registro na terceira tabela ficaria assim:

```
ID: 1 | Categoria: 1 | Produto: 1
ID: 2 | Categoria: 1 | Produto: 2
ID: 3 | Categoria: 1 | Produto: 3
ID: 4 | Categoria: 1 | Produto: 4
```

Sendo que cada produto inserido foi um checkbox marcado e o produto é relacionado a categoria 1 (1 = ID da categoria)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontrei em um artigo e vou postar a solução com um link.

O que eu queria é exatamente o que está neste artigo, inserir multiplos valores em uma tabela do banco de dados de forma dinamica onde o primeiro insert poderia ter 3 valores o segundo 6 valores e assim em diante.

gerar a string SQL com todos os valores a serem inseridos, separados por vírgula, de forma a executar a consulta apenas uma vez.

Logo, podemos fazer isto:

```
$valores = range( 1 , 10 );
$sql = sprintf( 'INSERT INTO tabela(numero) VALUES (%s)', implode( '), (' , $valores ) );
$DB->query( $sql );
```

Se dermos um echo em $sql, teremos como saída:

```
INSERT INTO tabela(numero) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)
```

Dessa forma só se executa a SQL uma vez, tornando a execução bem mais rápida.

Fonte: http://rberaldo.com.br/inserindo-multiplos-registros-em-tabela-de-banco-de-dados/

Answer (score 6):

MySQL não suporta insert em multi-tabelas. Ou seja, não é possivel inserir com uma unica query dados em diferentes tabelas.

Contudo, ele suporta a inserção de vários dados em uma unica tabela de uma unica vez (inserção em batch). Ex:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

MySQL Insert: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: O que eu quero é exatamente isso, inserir vários dados em uma única tabela, pois as duas primeiras já estão preenchidas com os devidos registros, o que eu desejo saber é o que eu devo fazer para realizar essa inserção de múltiplos registros pois os inserts nem sempre terão a mesma quantidade de registros, pode ser que em uma primeira inserção eu relacione 2 produtos a uma categoria depois eu relacione 5 produtos a outra categoria, então eu queria saber se tenho que fazer um loop ou algo parecido para que o insert saiba quantos registros serão inseridos.

Comment: Se eu entendi direito, então não. Você não precisa fazer nenhum loop na hora de inserir o novos valores. Sobre o fato de relacionar diferentes produtos em diferentes categorias, não interfere em nada na query. Você pode fazer tudo isso na mesma query. Basta você ajustar o seu código para isso.

Comment: Mas é exatamente isso que não estou sabendo, qual é a lógica para inserir vários dados ao mesmo tempo na tabela em um único insert.