# inserir na tabela só a linha que recebe valor na coluna da data

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho este código:

```
<?php
$result_cursos = "SELECT nome,
                         Quarto 

FROM centrodb.utentes

WHERE descricaovalencia = 'LAR' AND nome <> 'CLASSE' AND ativo = '1' ORDER BY nome ASC;";

    $resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);

$tabela1 .= '<div style="float: center" table align="center">';

$tabela1 .= '<table border="5">';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .='<thead>';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="200" text-align="center">Utente</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="30" text-align="center">Quarto</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="80" text-align="center">Data Registo</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="80" text-align="center">Micção</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="80" text-align="center">Dejecção</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="80" text-align="center">Colaborador</th>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</thead>'; 

$tabela1 .='<tbody>';

while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<td WIDTH="200" align="center"> <input type="text"  name= "NomeUtente" id= "NomeUtente" value="'.$rows_cursos['nome'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td WIDTH="30" align="center"> <input type="text" style="WIDTH="30" align="center" name= "Quarto" id= "Quarto" value="'.$rows_cursos['Quarto'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td WIDTH="80" align="center"> <input type="date" name= "DataRegisto" value="echo date("Y-m-d")"</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td WIDTH="80" align="center"> <input type="checkbox" name= "Miccao" value="Realizado"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td WIDTH="80" align="center"> <input type="checkbox" name= "Dejeccao" value="Realizado"></td>';

    $tabela1 .= '<td WIDTH="80" align="center"> <select name="Colaborador" id="Colaborador">
   <option></option>
    <option value="1">teste</option>

$tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 
}
$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela1 .= '</table>';

$tabela1 .= '</div>';

echo "<form method='POST' action=''>";
echo $tabela1;   

echo "<input type='submit' name='registar' value='Registo'>";

echo "</form>";

echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";

?>
```

Agora utilizo este código para inserir na tabela da base de dados:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['registar']))
{
$utente = $_POST['NomeUtente'];
$quarto = $_POST['Quarto'];
$data = $_POST['DataRegisto'];
$miccao = $_POST['Miccao'];
$dejeccao = $_POST['Dejeccao'];
$colaborador = $_POST['Colaborador'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO registoMiDe (NomeUtente, Quarto, DataRegisto, Miccao, Dejeccao, Colaborador) VALUES ('$utente', '$quarto', '$data', '$miccao', '$dejeccao', '$colaborador' )";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

}

?>
```

O problema é que só insere se preencher a última linha da tabela que mostro na imagem.
Eu pretendo que ele insira as linhas que eu preencher na tabela da imagem e insira os campos todos da linha. Não estou a fazer um `update`, quero mesmo fazer um `insert into`

Comment: o que não está funcionando, qual o erro?

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual, ele não dá erro e insere, mas só insere a última linha, eu pretendo que ele insira todas as linhas que eu preencha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, você tem um único comando, é natural que só vai inserir 1x. Se você tem várias linhas na tabela e quer inserir todos você precisa executar vários *inserts*, ou executar o comando várias vezes dentro de um *loop*.

Você precisa mudar o nome dos controles pra dizer que é um *array*, por exemplo `name="NomeUtente[]"`.  Faça isso com todos os demais campos.

Daí você faz um *loop*, com `for` por exemplo, contando quantos dados existem, usando `count`. O código seria algo como:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["NomeUtente"]);$i++) {
   $utente = $_POST['NomeUtente'][$i];
   // faça o mesmo com os outros campos, usando o índice $i ...

   $sql = "INSERT INTO registoMiDe (NomeUtente, Quarto, DataRegisto, Miccao, Dejeccao, Colaborador) VALUES ('$utente', '$quarto', '$data', '$miccao', '$dejeccao', '$colaborador' )";

   // dai executa o $sql inserindo cada dado ...
}
```

Você pode também gerar um único comando com múltiplos `values` e executar o `insert` uma única vez, veja essa outra pergunta se interessar: [Como gravar varios registros em uma tabela ao mesmo tempo MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54410/como-gravar-varios-registros-em-uma-tabela-ao-mesmo-tempo-mysql)